# How to evaluate below expression involving asymptotic notations?

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

If

```
f(n)=ϴ(n),g(n)=ϴ(n)
```

and

```
h(n)=Ω(n)
```

Then how to evaluate `f(n)g(n)+h(n)`?

I approached like `f(n)g(n)=ϴ(n^2)`, now what will be `Ω(n)+ϴ(n^2)`. According to me the lower bound of this expression should be `Ω(n)`, and upper bound should be `O(n^2)`, but what should be the tightest bound for this expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some constants `k1, k2, l1, l2 and m > 0`, we have:

```
f(n) is ϴ(n)

    => k1*n < f(n) < k2*n, for n sufficiently large

g(n) is ϴ(n)

    => l1*n < g(n) < g2*n, for n sufficiently large

h(n) is Ω(n)

    => m*n < h(n), for n sufficiently large
```

Then, `f(n)*h(n)`:

```
for f(n) * h(n): 

    k1*l1*n^2 < f(n)*g(n) < k2*l2*n^2, for n sufficiently large
```

So we can just write `p(n) = f(n)*g(n)` and use constants `c1=k1*l1` and `c2=k2*l2`, and we have:

```
p(n) (= f(n)*g(n)) is in ϴ(n^2), since

    c1*n^2 < p(n) < c2*n^2
```

Then, finally, what complexity does `p(n) + h(n)` have? We have:

```
c1*n^2 + m*n < p(n) + h(n), for n sufficiently large
```

Since we never got an upper bound on `h(n)`, we can't really say anything regarding the upper bound on `p(n) + h(n)`. This is imperative: `h(n) in Ω(n)` only says that `h(n)` grows at least as fast as `n` (linear) asymptotically, but we don't know if this is a tight lower bound. It might be a very sloppy lower bound for a exponential time function.

Subsequently, we can only state something regarding the lower bound:

```
p(n) + h(n) = f(n)*g(n) + h(n) is in Ω(n^2)
```

I.e., `f(n)*g(n) + h(n)` grows at least as `n^2` (i.e., in `Ω(n^2)`) asymptotically.

---

A note as to your approach: you are right (as shown above) that `f(n)g(n) is in ϴ(n^2)`, but note that this implies that a tight lower bound of `f(n)g(n) + h(n)` can never be less than `k*n^2`: i.e., `f(n)g(n) + h(n) in Ω(n^2)` is a given, and a better (tigher) lower bound than what your suggested; `Ω(n)`. Recall that the fastest growing terms dominate asymptotic behavior.

For reference, see e.g.

- https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/asymptotic-notation

Comment: Just one confusion in your explanation , you said that "Since we never got an upper bound on h(n), we can't really say anything regarding the upper bound on p(n) + h(n)" , but we got an upper bound on p(n) which is O(n^2) , so why can't overall upper bound be O(n^2) since fastest growing terms dominate asymptotic behaviour.

Comment: Let' take an example: let's say that function `h(n)=n^3`. The given lower bound `h(n) is in Ω(n)` is still _valid_, even if it's not a very good lower bound. A statement regarding `big-Ω(q(n))` notation for some function `h(n)` only tells us that the _asymptotic behaviour of a `h(n)` grows **faster** than the given lower bound `q(n)`, for some constant `k` and `n` sufficiently large_. Hence, there is no demand (nor guarantee) that bound `Ω(q(n))` is a _good_ or _tight_ bound (even if we generally would want it to be), only that it is a _lower_ bound. For this example, `p(n)+h(n) is in O(n^3)`.